# Extract values from json string

Tags: json, swift, swift2, nsjsonserialization

Below is json string from the json data I got and convert to string. I need to extract values like order_id, order_number, price.

```
Optional({
    msg = Success;
    name = "Add Order";
    "order_id" = 40509;
    "order_number" = 012720380116;
    "price" = 115;
    status = 1;
})
```

I tried to get values with NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData but gives me nothing. What is wrong with my code, could someone take a look?

```
do {
let json:AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
if let order_number = json!["order_number"] as? String {
print(order_number)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast appropriately.

```
let json = try 
   NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
   as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Comment: The problem could by your JSON then. Make sure the `order_number` is really a string and not a number.

Comment: some values is number and some others are string.

Comment: Your answer is applying exactly my solution (`NSDictionary` and `[String: Anyobject]` are equivalent). You need to cast to the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use following code block on do-catch and it worked

```
                let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary
            if let stat = jsonDict!["status"] {
                if stat as! NSObject == 1 {
                    let order_id = jsonDict!["order_id"]
                    let order_number = jsonDict!["order_number"]
                    let price = jsonDict!["price"]

                }
            }
```